# Change ViewModel for a View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, viewmodel

I need my view changes dynamically model validation in my application. For example

**Entity Framework Model**

```
    public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string  LastName { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModelFirstName**

```
    public class ViewModelName
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModelLastName**

```
    public class ViewModelLastName
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Initially my View will use one of these ViewModel. Is there a way to change it dynamically?

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: This is very unusual. Are you sure you don't want a single `ViewModel` that performs validation based on some condition checks? Have a look at implementing the `IValidatableObject` interface and create a `Validate` method, that might serve your purpose in a more traditional fashion.

Comment: I need to allow the user to change model validation in my application. The only thing that came to my mind is that of switching viewmodel.

Comment: Use jquery.validation You may change validation dynamically depends on your needs

Comment: I need do this server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define interface

```
public interface IModelName
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

implement it in your models and use this interface as model for your view

Comment: I could change model validation with this method with Ioc Container, right?

Comment: Or just implementing this interface in different classes and pass required instances of those classes into your view.